# Web filter in Android, "Safe Browsing" feature

Tags: android, security, filter

I am looking for a way to get a website URL before it is opened and prevent browser from opening it if URL is one of blacklisted. The closest analog is Safe-Browsing function from Lookout Mobile Security. However it works only with default browser, but even that would be great.

As I know it is not possible to do for all kind of browsers because we need a rooted phone and modify iptables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like a hack, however it works and this is the way most of web filters and anti-viruses work in android.
You have to create a contentObserver that monitors browser history. Opened links appear in the list when page is almost loaded. When it is up to you how to react.